# Meaning of 'cs' in R expression

Tags: r

I inherited legacy code from 2009 that includes the many of the following types of expressions -

```
variable %in% cs(do, ph, t, secchi)
```

I get the following error - Error: could not find function "cs" when I try to run anything like this, have not seen 'cs' before, and can't locate any info in help files, google, or on this site so far.  I'm guessing it is a deprecated way of concatenating strings but would like to confirm before I update the legacy code.

Comment: it is possibly a typo, try replacing it with `c(do, ph, t, secchi)`

Comment: There is a `gamlss::cs` function, but it really would no make sense in this context.There's a `hsphase::cs` but it only takes 3 arguments. Found a couple of other packages with `cs` functions but they also take fewer arguments than you are demonstrating. The code should have library(.) calls. You should examine them and report back and do include more detail about the domain of science you are supporting..

Comment: and maybe further `variable %in% c("do","ph","t","secchi")` ... ? http://abstrusegoose.com/432 ...

Comment: My guess after doing a bit of googling is that `do` == "dissolved oxygen; `ph` == "pH",`t` =="temperature" and `secchi` == "Secchi depth".

Comment: My downvote and closevote are for lack of clarity and failure to respond to reasonable requests for clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `Cs` function in `Hmisc` package. I think it is that.

See [this](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/hmisc/docs/Cs)

```
library(Hmisc)
Cs(a,cat,dog)
```

Comment: This has the potential to win the guessing game.

Comment: I see no reason for upvoting for WAGs.

Comment: I believe this is the answer based on what it seems to do in the code.  Thank you for the input